# why is a numpy view backwards?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=np.uint8)
data.view(np.uint64)
```

What I would expect is the binary would be:

```
0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

but instead the 8 bit groups are reversed.

```
np.array([72057594037927936], dtype=np.uint64)
```

which is:

```
0b0000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Why is that?
Is there computation being done that reverses this or is this just the layout?

Comment: Intel based CPUs are "little endian", least significant bytes come first.

Comment: But the original ordering of the list in the numpy array didn't have an ordering of least or greatest.

Comment: Originally you created a sequence of single bytes (interpreted as uint8 without meaning of least or most significant). The sequence order is kept and the one-byte has the highest memory address. Then you reinterpreted the 8 bytes as a uint64 where the most significant byte is now 1, the others are 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct with the how binary data is order in your array. Instead of viewing as `uint64`, you can view as 8 bytes (`V8` dtype):

```py
import numpy as np
np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=np.uint8).view('V8')[0]
# void(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01')
```

However your CPU is using [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) ordering of bytes to represent integers. This means that when viewing the bytes as `uint64`, you get a really big number.

You can check this as follows using the [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) package:

```py
import struct
import sys

print(sys.bybteorder)
# 'little'

# view these bytes as uint64 with little endian gives a big number
struct.unpack('<Q', b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01')[0]
# 72057594037927936

# view these bytes as uint64 with big endian gives 1
struct.unpack('>Q', b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01')[0]
# 1

# view these bytes as uint64 with native endian gives a big number with your CPU
struct.unpack('=Q', b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01')[0]
# 72057594037927936
```